# doc frequency for multiple fields in single query in elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene

how to get doc frequency of multiple fields in single query. If we query with name and address.  it should return docfrequency of name index and lat_long index based on the inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do it in a single query. Why not multiple queries, but not retrieving the full document when you don't need it (so it's faster).

Comment: Is it possible to do this by adding aggregation ? We are able to get doc frequency of single field using aggregation but how to achieve this for multiple fields in single query? Is there a way to do by aggregation of aggregations ?

Comment: @ Ali Hashemi  do you have any updates for my above comments ?